# Heroku nodejs ssl

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku

I am trying to use [`node-heroku-ssl-redirect'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-ssl-redirect) and when trying to connect I get an error on the server:

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=OPTIONS path="xxx" host=xxx request_id=51d7cf7c-9c3d-432a-b1ea-954e02218a16 fwd="68.173.135.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

And on the website:

Failed to load xxx: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I listen on port 3000 as it is in the example.

Comment: in response to the preflight ie 'OPTIONS'  u need a route specified that will return  the hdr required per CORS  ... { Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*' }

Comment: How I can do it for all responsnes in nodejs?